# SQL Server: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, timestamp

When using this statement

```
create table demo (
    ts timestamp
)

insert into demo select current_timestamp
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column

How do I insert the current time to a `timestamp` column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2K - Insert explicit value for timestamp column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291632/sql-server-2k-insert-explicit-value-for-timestamp-column)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), `timestamp`

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary
>   numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The
>   timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime
>   data type.

You're probably looking for the `datetime` data type instead.

Answer (score 35):

If you have a need to copy the exact same timestamp data, change the data type in the destination table from timestamp to binary(8) -- i used varbinary(8) and it worked fine.

This obviously breaks any timestamp functionality in the destination table, so make sure you're ok with that first.

Comment: Thanks! This is especially helpful when creating an archive database to move stuff to after a certain amount of time. In the stored procs, I have to put every column in the list because of that error, but now I can replace it with * so I don't need to modify my proc every time I add columns to the matching tables in both databases.

Comment: also useful if you need to use a table variable for partial results and you want the original timestamp to be included in the final result

Comment: This one is a very good answer. I had a table variable in a stored procedure and had to insert the result of a select query into that table before returning it, changing the type of the column in the table variable to [varbinary](8) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 18):

You can't insert the values into timestamp column explicitly. It is auto-generated. Do not use this column in your insert statement. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(SQL.90).aspx for more details.

You could use a datetime instead of a timestamp like this:

```
create table demo (
    ts datetime
)

insert into demo select current_timestamp

select ts from demo
```

Returns:

```
2014-04-04 09:20:01.153
```

Answer (score 16):

### How to insert current time into a timestamp with SQL Server:

In newer versions of SQL Server, `timestamp` is renamed to `RowVersion`.  Rightly so, because timestamp name is misleading.

SQL Server's `timestamp` IS NOT set by the user and does not represent a date or a time.  Timestamp is only good for making sure a row hasn't changed since it's been read.

If you want to store a date or a time, do not use timestamp, you must use one of the other datatypes, like for example `datetime`, `smalldatetime`, `date`, `time` or `DATETIME2`

For example:

```
create table foo (
    id INT,
    leet timestamp
)

insert into foo (id) values (15)

select * from foo

15    0x00000000000007D3
```

'timestamp' in mssql is some kind of internal datatype.  Casting that number to datetime produces a nonsense number.

Answer (score 7):

Assume Table1 and Table2 have three columns A, B and TimeStamp. I want to insert from Table1 into Table2.

This fails with the timestamp error:

```
Insert Into Table2
Select Table1.A, Table1.B, Table1.TimeStamp From Table1
```

This works:

```
Insert Into Table2
Select Table1.A, Table1.B, null From Table1
```

Answer (score 6):

There is some good information in these answers. Suppose you are dealing with databases which you can't alter, and that you are copying data from one version of the table to another, or from the same table in one database to another. Suppose also that there are lots of columns, and you either need data from all the columns, or the columns which you don't need don't have default values. You need to write a query with all the column names.

Here is a query which returns all the non-timestamp column names for a table, which you can cut and paste into your insert query. FYI: 189 is the type ID for timestamp.

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(50) = 'Product';

select stuff(
    (select 
        ', ' + columns.name
    from 
        (select id from sysobjects where xtype = 'U' and name = @TableName) tables
        inner join syscolumns columns on tables.id = columns.id
    where columns.xtype <> 189
    for xml path('')), 1, 2, '')
```

Just change the name of the table at the top from 'Product' to your table name. The query will return a list of column names:

```
ProductID, Name, ProductNumber, MakeFlag, FinishedGoodsFlag, Color, SafetyStockLevel, ReorderPoint, StandardCost, ListPrice, Size, SizeUnitMeasureCode, WeightUnitMeasureCode, Weight, DaysToManufacture, ProductLine, Class, Style, ProductSubcategoryID, ProductModelID, SellStartDate, SellEndDate, DiscontinuedDate, rowguid, ModifiedDate
```

If you are copying data from one database (DB1) to another database(DB2) you could use this query.

```
insert DB2.dbo.Product (ProductID, Name, ProductNumber, MakeFlag, FinishedGoodsFlag, Color, SafetyStockLevel, ReorderPoint, StandardCost, ListPrice, Size, SizeUnitMeasureCode, WeightUnitMeasureCode, Weight, DaysToManufacture, ProductLine, Class, Style, ProductSubcategoryID, ProductModelID, SellStartDate, SellEndDate, DiscontinuedDate, rowguid, ModifiedDate)
select ProductID, Name, ProductNumber, MakeFlag, FinishedGoodsFlag, Color, SafetyStockLevel, ReorderPoint, StandardCost, ListPrice, Size, SizeUnitMeasureCode, WeightUnitMeasureCode, Weight, DaysToManufacture, ProductLine, Class, Style, ProductSubcategoryID, ProductModelID, SellStartDate, SellEndDate, DiscontinuedDate, rowguid, ModifiedDate 
from DB1.dbo.Product
```

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION getColumns (
  TableName nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS
BEGIN 
 DECLARE return_value nvarchar(max);
    select return_value= stuff((select ', ' + columns.name from (select id from sysobjects where xtype = 'U' and name = TableName) tables
        inner join syscolumns columns on tables.id = columns.id
    where columns.xtype <> 189
    for xml path('')), 1, 2, '');
 RETURN return_value
END;

Answer (score 2):

```
create table demo (
    id int,
    ts timestamp
)

insert into demo(id,ts) 
 values (1, DEFAULT)
```

Comment: This answer at least acknowledges part of the error message that I find confusing, although it doesn't really answer the user's question (I'm not the one who downvoted the answer).