# How to store current Date and time in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a java program where I used java.util.Date to fetch current date and time and I have a table in mysql having a field as

```
ActivityTime date; // date is the type
```

And I used prepared statement to insert in the table.

```
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
long t = today.getTime();

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "insert into UserActivity values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
....
ps.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(t));
....
```

Date is shown correct in output but time is 00:00:00 I don't know why is this happening ?
Please help me to fetch time also. 
When I printed java.util.date is shows correct time. Problem is how to insert time into sql table.

PS: May be this is very simple but java api is new to me

Comment: or even this `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using MySQL datetime field type and then use the function `NOW()` to insert a value to it.

You would insert the date like so:

```
INSERT INTO `table-name`(`DATETIME-FIELD-NAME`) VALUES(NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `java.sql.Timestamp`, even better you can handle this at database end, just set default value

```
create table test (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: `timestamp` should only be used for table versioning. use `datetime`instead.

Comment: @jue , could you please elaborate it little more

Comment: see here: [cannot-insert-into-timestamp-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262426/)

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "insert into UserActivity values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
....
ps.setDate(5, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
....
```

---

hope can help for you

Comment: Suppose I insert System.currentTimeMillis() in database then can I be able to convert these Millisecs to date ?

Comment: of course use this `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)`

Comment: Thanks jun xia, This approach works very fine and thanks to all answerers too :)

Comment: Better yet, use time stamp and set its default to current time stamp. Time stamp uses half the storage of date time and it much easier for the db to index on if needed