# Timestamp error in sql

Tags: java, sql

I am doing a java program in which i read input from some files and timestamp is one among that.I had created a table with timestamp and when I insert the timestamp it throws error like
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '10'"

I had created a table as follows

```
create table profile(text varchar,time timestamp,primary key(text));
```

for instance if the timestamp read is "2014-05-26 10:23:35.0".when i m inserting into the table ,it shows the error as i said earlier.
also this is my insert query ,I have timestamp value in timestamp  and text value in text variables of java

```
insert into profile values('text',timestamp);
```

can anyone tell me how to resolve this

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you share your insert query

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10262454/1166894

Comment: timestamp is not what you think it is - use DateTime

Comment: @Mark..thankz for ur reply..I have that value in timestamp variable of java ....By using DateTime data type in sql,can I insert that timestamp variable of java directly or we have to make any changes

Comment: but when i used datetime data type it again shows the same error

Comment: @Reddevil As an alternate solution, use a table level trigger to update timestamp value of profile table rather than passing from Java.

Comment: @Polppan..but timestamp value is not the current time of the system..it may be anything

Comment: @Reddevil Have a look at [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2333134?start=0&tstart=0), might be helpful.