# Get inserted timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

in our T-SQL database We have some timestamp column, every time we insert or update a record we select the timestamp from the record the same key we inserted or updated.

We want avoid the double search: for update and for select, we tried something like this:

```
declare @table table(id int, val timestamp not null)
declare @table2 table(val timestamp)

insert @table(id) 
output inserted.val into @table2
values (1)
```

but it does not compile, i have an error in Italian, something like 'a timestamp column can not be set explicitly'

any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TIMESTAMP is a data type that is automatically generated and only exposed as read-only. It's based around an incrementing number within the system.

[SQL Server: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262426/sql-server-cannot-insert-an-explicit-value-into-a-timestamp-column)

Try this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(id INT, val TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE(val DATETIME)

INSERT @table (id)
OUTPUT inserted.val INTO @table2(val)
VALUES (1)

SELECT
  t.id,
  t.val,
  CONVERT( TIMESTAMP, t2.val ) AS table2_timestamp
FROM
  @table AS t,
  @table2 AS t2
```