# Import Data to Existing Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

How to import data to existing table in Database from another Database in sql

I am trying this but not working . It is saying

> 'Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column.' Use `INSERT` with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a `DEFAULT` into the `timestamp` column.

```
Insert Into [test].[dbo].[Sample$Employee]
select * from [Test1].[dbo].[Sample1$Employee]
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  Please tag with the actual database you are using.  Also, you may try searching Stack Overflow for your problem before posting.

Comment: Give some details about table schema also

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262426/sql-server-cannot-insert-an-explicit-value-into-a-timestamp-column

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
INSERT INTO <database>.<schema>.<table>
SELECT * FROM <source_database>.<schema>.<source_table>
```

After your modification, you need specify columns which you want the insert to the new table.

So your query could be

```
INSERT INTO <database>.<schema>.<table>([Column1], [Column1], [Column1])
SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3] FROM <source_database>.<schema>.source_table>
```

As I can see from the error message, you need implicitly define a column type.

For example: If your column has type DATE you need use CAST(Column AS DATE) AS [Column_Name].

Comment: How is this different from the query in the question?

Comment: Previously it was a little bit other. it was SELECT INTO.

Comment: It was an `insert into` from the beginning: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48982675/1

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Target_Table(Column1, Column2, Column3)  
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3  
FROM Source_Database.Source_Table
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The error message actually gives you the answer you are looking for:

> Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

**EDIT**

`TIMESTAMP` columns cannot be explicitly written to, and you need to exclude this column from your insert statement, or... if you really want the timestamp data moved from the source table, then you will need to change the type of the corresponding field in the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Your table has a column of type [`timestamp`, aka `rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql). A column of this type cannot be written to.

Instead of using `*`, which includes the column you can't copy, write out the column list and omit the colum of type `timestamp`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select * into SQLShackDemo.HumanResources.Department 
from AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department
```

Comment: How is this different from the query in the question?