# Getting error Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to import data from mysql to SQL Server, but when I run the sql query it I get an error

> Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column

I know in `modified_date` column there is default current timestamp, so it doesn't allow me to insert that date, but I need to import same data in SQL Server which is in Mysql database.

Can anyone please help me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't insert the values into `timestamp` column explicitly. It is auto-generated. Better alter your column datatype to `datetime`.

Comment: Ok, let me try that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48982675/330315

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server has **nothing to do** with a date and/or time. It's a **binary, system-internal counter** only, and you **cannot** insert values into a column of type `TIMESTAMP`. If you want to record the date and time of something, use `DATE` (if date only) or `DATETIME2(n)` (if you need both date and time portions)

Comment: It works now thanks.