# Error while inserting data using sequelize in mssql db

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I get this error "RequestError: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.".

My database schema looks something like this ,

```
class Owner extends Model {}
Owner.init({
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  }, { sequelize,timestamps: false });

class Hotel extends Model {}
Hotel.init({
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
  }, { sequelize,timestamps: false });


  class Users extends Model {}
  Users.init({
    name: Sequelize.STRING
  }, { sequelize,timestamps: false });

class User_Hotel extends Model {}
User_Hotel.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      }
    }, { sequelize,timestamps: false });

class Hotel_Owner extends Model {}
Hotel_Owner.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      }
    }, { sequelize,timestamps: false });

Owner.belongsToMany(Hotel, { through: { model: Hotel_Owner, unique: false } });
Hotel.belongsToMany(Owner, { through: { model: Hotel_Owner, unique: false } });


Hotel.belongsToMany(Users, { through: { model: User_Hotel, unique: false } });
Users.belongsToMany(Hotel, { through: { model: User_Hotel, unique: false } });
```

Now, I have to insert data in my tables, which I do something like this.

```
hotel = Hotel.create({name:"WestIn"});
[owner,created] = Owner.findOrCreate({where:{name:"John Doe"}});

Hotel_Owner.create({OwnerId: owner.id, HotelId: hotel.id });

user = Users.create({name:"Common man"});

User_Hotel.create({ HotelId: hotel.id , UsersId:user.id});
```

I am not sure , why I am getting this error.

Comment: Hi, you tagged your question [tag:mysql], but you mention MSSQL (a common abbreviation of Microsoft SQL Server) in your question. I have never seen the error message come from MySQL, but it seems to be well known for Microsoft SQL Server, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262426/sql-server-cannot-insert-an-explicit-value-into-a-timestamp-column

Comment: Show generated SQL that causes the error

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. I will note that most of Sequelize's methods return Promises so you should be `await`ing just about everything, e.g.: `hotel = await Hotel.create({name:"WestIn"});`

Comment: Yeah,, I actually found the error. The association tables that I have explicitly made, do not contain fields for `Hoteld` and `UserId` , which is why I was getting that Error. The error message is not appropriate. It is no where related to timestamps, rather it signifies that the column I am trying to insert doesn't exist in the table.